# Two Obscure Questions About Space Complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, space-complexity

1.) Suppose I have the function below that takes in a list with size n:

```
def foo(lst):
  n = len(lst)
  for i in range(n):
    n.append(i)
  return n
```

In this case, how would we explain the input space complexity?

Initially, of course, the input takes up space proportional to the size of the list (n): O(n). However, since we are appending an element to the input list, its size will become 2n. Therefore, the amount of space taken up by the input is directly proportional to 2n, which, using big O notation, still simplifies to O(n). Is this the correct interpretation?

---

2.) Suppose I have the function below that takes in a list with length n and a positive integer k. There is no input validation, though it is assumed that k must be at most equal to n:

```
def foo(lst, k):
  n = len(lst)
  for i in range(n - k + 1):
    cool = lst[i: i + k]
    if sum(cool) == 15:
      return cool
```

In this case, how would we explain the auxiliary space complexity? While we are only ever storing one list (since we continually overwrite the same variable), the list's size differs based on the input of k.

So, for instance, if k = 1 (best case), then we would be storing an empty list for each iteration. If k = 2, then we would be storing a 2-element list for each iteration. However, if k = n (the worst-case), we would be storing an n-element list on its lone iteration. Thus, if we were to just consider auxiliary space complexity, would it be fair to say that it is worst-case O(n)?

Comment: There's no standard thing called "input space complexity". Your function in 1 allocates Theta(n) more memory, so it's reasonable to say it uses O(n) auxiliary storage. In 2, I'd say it's O(k). For GC'ed languages, you have to treat "auxiliary memory" as the most active memory allocated at any point in time. (note: overwriting the same variable isn't relevant except in as much as the variable is the only reference to the slice, so affects what memory is reachable).

Comment: You can say "worst case" O(n) for 2, but I don't know why that would be better or clearer than saying O(k).

Comment: Ok. So, if we were to append elements to the original input, it would still count as auxiliary space and not part of the input space?

Comment: Yes, because attending to the input causes more memory to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Please, be careful that your code is correct when you provide snippets. It should be

```
def foo(lst):
  n = len(lst)
  for i in range(n):
    lst.append(i)
  return n
```

The first question: yes, your list will be 2n in size, which makes it O(n).

The second question, inside the for loop you are not creating anything new, just summing the elements in a subarray. This does not add any memory therefore the space is still O(n), and O(1) auxiliary memory.

Comment: `list[i : i+k]` may not be a subarray -- if `lst` is a numpy array then yes, but if it's a python list, then it's a new slice copied out from the list.